# Crash when creating UIImage from Data

Tags: ios, swift, crash, uiimage

In my application, I'm attempting to instantiate a `UIImage` from `Data`. I've been seeing some crash logs come in from App Store Connect showing that my code is crashing on this particular line:

```swift
guard let data = photo.data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return nil }
```

Below is the backtrace. `PhotoCache` is the last object I have control over, and `.imageFor(_:)` is the method that the line above is contained in.

[image: Crash Logs]

What is `PFEvanscentData`, and what might be causing it to crash in this scenario?

Edit: Here is the full method.

```swift
private var cache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
    
func imageFor(_ photo: Photo) -> UIImage? {
    guard let key = photo.id as NSString? else { return nil }
    if let image = cache.object(forKey: key) {
        return image
    }
    guard let data = photo.data, let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return nil }
    cache.setObject(image, forKey: key)
    return image
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `image = UIImage(data: data)` is your problem line? By default UIImage from data doesn't cache so do you use any third party to cache images?

Comment: I am using an `NSCache` object, but this line of code is in the code path where the requested image is _not_ in the cache, and has to initialize from scratch. So it shouldn't be affected by the `NSCache`. I will update the post with the full method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be in memory warnings. NSCache do not guarantee to remove cached images after receiving a memory warning. I would suggest to subclass NSCache and inside subclass listen (using `NSNotificationCenter`) for `didReceiveMemoryWarningNotification` and if you get an warning remove elements from cache.

Answer (score 0):

There are known thread safety issues with `UIImage(data:)` calls. A simple `NSLock` protection might help in this.

```
    lock.lock()
    let image = UIImage(data: data)
    lock.unlock()
```

References :

**Alamofire** https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage/blob/master/Source/UIImage%2BAlamofireImage.swift#L38-L53

**AFNetworking** https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/3e8addb6537df7ae535df402680a4be93ae7a6a6/AFNetworking/AFURLResponseSerialization.m#L522-L533

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be an issue of using an objective-c class within this swift class.  I'm looking at the line

```
Data._unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveC
```

You probably need to double check that the NSData coming from Objective-C is actually non-nil and is being converted to the correct type that you are sending to the UIImage initializer, since there's nothing that's actively enforcing that on the Obj-C side you should make sure it is correct on the swift side.